# How to automate web whatsapp to send messases with win32 api and pyautogui?

Tags: python, winapi, automation, whatsapp, pyautogui

Can anyone tell me how can I automate web WhatsApp to send msgs to every person in the contect list
or suggest me a better option to do so, just remember I cant buy paid APIs.

Comment: open https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone}&text={text} with webbrowser. after that, sleep 3,click and press enter to send.

Comment: I have posted this as a Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use web.whatsapp.com url:

```
import webbrowser
import time
import pyautogui
phone = "12345678901"
text = "my message"
webbrowser.open(f"https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={phone}&text={text}&app_absent=0")
time.sleep(9) # wait for whatsapp web
pyautogui.click() # move your mouse to textbox before
pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried matan h's answers and found couple of mistakes.

I have updated URL as mentioned in below code.

```
import webbrowser
import time
import pyautogui as gui

m_number = '91987654321'  #country code and mobile number without '+' symbol
message = "You........"
url = 'https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone='+m_number+'&text='+message+'&app_absent=0'
webbrowser.open(url)
time.sleep(10) #loading page time
gui.press('enter')
```

Comment: Please use the correct formatting when inserting your code

Comment: thank you, I have fixed the mistakes in my answer.